# Local notification to be fired on next midnight

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification, nscalendar

I want to schedule a local notification at 12.01 AM next day.. I am unable to set the time to 12.. Even if I set it to 12, it does not get set to 12 but takes some other time.

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc]initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:(NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit) fromDate:[NSDate date]]; 
NSLog(@"components %@",components); 
[components setHour:00]; 
[components setMinute:01]; 
[components setSecond:00];
```

I use this snippet..
I set notification.fireDate as

> [calendar dateFromComponents:components];

But when i log the date, it displays yesterday's date with 3.42 as time

Comment: Can you show the code you're actually using to achieve this? What other time does it become?

Comment: NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc]initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:(NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit |  NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit) fromDate:[NSDate date]]; 
    NSLog(@"components %@",components);
    [components setHour:00];
    [components setMinute:01];
    [components setSecond:00];
I use this snippet.. I set notification.fireDate as [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
But when i log the date, it displays yesterday's date with 3.42 as time

Comment: You couldn't find the edit link?

Comment: sorry I'm new to SO and i dunno..Can u tell me how to notify pls

Comment: I'm not sure what your comment means. The faq might help you http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Comment: I asked for an answer to that midnight notification rene

Comment: Ah, I'm not an Ios developer so I have no clue, but based on your initial question I was pretty sure that knowledgable people would not have enough info to answer your question. It has improved now, so all you have to do now is wait...